# How to tell explode to ignore line feeds?

Tags: php, explode

I have written some small code to read in a flat text file and display it. My issue is that one of the fields has alot of text in it and also some line returns. My code is using the line return is a delimiter and moving onto the next record.

How can I tell it to only split by the delimiter and ignore line returns?

Sample code I am using:

```
$delimiter = chr(1);

$fp = fopen('app2','r');
if (!$fp) {echo 'ERROR: Unable to open file.</table></body></html>'; exit;}

$loop = 0;
while (!feof($fp)) {
  $loop++;
    $line = fgets($fp,2048); //use 2048 if very long lines
    $field[$loop] = explode ($delimiter, $line);
    echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$field[$loop][0].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][1].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][2].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][3].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][4].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][5].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][6].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][7].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][8].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][9].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][10].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][11].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][12].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][13].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][14].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][15].'</td>
<td>'.$field[$loop][16].'</td>

</tr>';
    $fp++;
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

You can see what it is doing here http://www.smartphonesoft.com/fred/xmlfeed/test/itunes_to_mysql.php

Comment: Your link requires authentication.

Comment: You will probably need a proper CSV parsing class to handle this.

Comment: You might not need a CSV parsing *class*, PHP has [simple CSV parsing built right in](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Comment: Why do you have `$fp++;` inside your loop?! `$fp` is your file pointer (handle). Is your 'large text field' surrounded in quotes or similar in order to identify the EOL inside the field as part of that field? May be you could preprocess your data to convert the EOL inside your data into some other character? Is your 'large text field' not the last field (ie. there are other field delimiters `chr(1)` after it)?

Answer (score 0):

You can paste your textfile into one `$var`, by jaust adding all with `.=` , as long as your file is not 2GB large.

> Note: string can be as large as 2GB.